How to export and send to email view page to PDF included CSS design from view?
I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project and I need with one click using Rotativa to export and send to mail view page as PDF including some CSS.
Here's the view:

This is the exported PDF:

And here is the controller code:
public Byte[] pdfList_file(int? uID, int? szID, string monat, string klid)
{
    if (uID == null || szID == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(uID)} or {nameof(szID)} is null.");

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(klid) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(monat))
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(klid)} or {nameof(monat)} cannot be null or empty.");

    // Generate PDF using Rotativa
    var pdf = new ActionAsPdf("Details", new { uID = uID, szID = szID })
    {
        FileName = $"{klid}_StundenZettel_{monat}.pdf",

        CustomSwitches =
            "--page-size A4 " +
            "--print-media-type " +
            "--margin-top 8mm --margin-bottom 8mm --margin-left 8mm --margin-right 8mm " +
            "--enable-local-file-access",

        Cookies = Request.Cookies?.AllKeys?.ToDictionary(k => k, k => Request.Cookies[k]?.Value)
                  ?? new Dictionary<string, string>()
    };

    // Generate and return PDF as a byte array
    return pdf.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);
}

public ActionResult SendAsPdf(int? uID, int? szID, string monat, string klid)
{
    //My code....
}

How to export PDF included view design?

FWIW this post is strikingly similar to another one posted about 20 minutes before, and subsequently deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79224657/126014
